# Scratchpad in GoJS similar to draw.io

Tags: gojs

I new to GoJs and in process of learning, I found GoJS is more similar to draw.io, but it misses the property of adding the diagram to palete, while it supports from palete to diagram.

ie., Moving the diagram from work area to toolbar , for reusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can absolutely do this, a `Palette` is just a `Diagram` with a few properties pre-set for you. Specifically, it is a `Diagram` with these properties set in the constructor:

```
this.allowDragOut = true;
this.allowMove = false;
this.isReadOnly = true;
this.contentAlignment = go.Spot.TopCenter;
this.layout = new go.GridLayout();
```

There is a sample of [Two Diagrams with checkboxes for relevant properties](https://gojs.net/latest/samples/twoDiagrams.html).

The simplest way to get the behavior you want is to set `allowDragOut` to `true` on both of your Diagrams.

Comment: See also the Add to Palette sample: https://gojs.net/latest/samples/addToPalette.html